# AndEngine - Scrolling a parallax background

Tags: android, andengine

I'm developing an `Android` game using `AndEngine`. I have a ParallaxBackground in the menuScene, where you can scroll the menu items until you find the one you want and click on it. I want certain parallax entities in the ParallaxBackground to scroll in varying speeds when the menu items are scrolled (for a cool effect ;) ); but have no idea how to do this.

ParallaxBackground doesn't have any public position changing methods, and neither do the ParallaxEntities themselves.

I've tried searching for a solution, but the best I found were a few addon classes made by users that others complain are incomplete.

Is there an implemented way (or a "trick") to doing this with the regular `AndEngine` GLES2?

Thank you

Comment: Can you not just set different speeds on each parallax entity you are attaching to your ParallaxBackground?